# Jackson (Java) : deserialization for the same property name but return different objects. for one it return object and second List<Object>

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a POJO like this:

```
 public class NewClass {

    String name;
    @JsonProperty("productType")
    ProductType productType2005;
    List<ProductType> productType;
   }
```

I want to deserialize json into Pojo. The issue is I have property name same productType but I can expect two different return types or data structures.

1. return `ProductType` object
2. return `List<ProductType>`
   since property name is the same how can I effectively use Jackson annotations to get it resolved?

I'm using rest-assured for deserialization and Lombok for typical getter and setters.

Comment: at a time only one property can exist at a time.

Comment: you question still unclear.. what do u want during serialization and deserialization?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, this isn't possible. A solution would be to expect a List of ProductType objects with a minimum of at least one if required.